# Sending Data to a Kinesis Firehose Delivery Stream with Direct PUT with CDK

Tags: aws-cdk, amazon-kinesis-firehose

So basically I want to send Json records to an S3 bucket using kinesis firehose.

Json data -> Kinesis firehose delivery stream -> S3

I have created a delivery stream with Direct PUT. Is there a way in CDK to send data to this delivery stream with node.js? All the documentation I can find around PutRecord/PutRecords is for Java.

The documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-kinesisfirehose-alpha-readme.html#direct-put) under AWS SDK also just provides a java example. Is there is a way to PutRecord or PutRecordBatch API call in node.js/cdk or node.js sdk?

I also want to transform the data before putting it in the S3 bucket (called eventLogBucket). Currently I am using step functions workflow in the CDK stack to do it like so:

```js
const putEventToS3 = new CallAwsService(this, 'S3 Put Object Step', {
  service: 's3',
  action: 'putObject',
  parameters: {
    Bucket: eventLogBucket.bucketName,
    Body: JsonPath.objectAt('$.S3Event'),
    ContentType: 'application/json',
    Key: JsonPath.stringAt('$.testKeyString'),
  },
  iamResources: [eventLogBucket.bucketArn],
})

const sendEventToS3 =
  Chain.start(eventTransformer).next(putEventToS3);
```

How can I replace putEventToS3 with kinesis PutRecords?

Following is my code for the delivery stream:

```js
 const firehoseRole = new iam.Role(this, 'firehoseRole', {
      assumedBy: new iam.ServicePrincipal('firehose.amazonaws.com'),
    });

    const firehoseeDeliveryStream = new CfnDeliveryStream(
      this,
      'FirehoseStreamToS3',
      {
        deliveryStreamName: 'test-firehose-delivery-stream',
        deliveryStreamType: 'DirectPut',
        s3DestinationConfiguration: {
          bucketArn: eventLogBucket.bucketArn,
          bufferingHints: {
            sizeInMBs: Size.mebibytes(5).toMebibytes(),
            intervalInSeconds: Duration.seconds(900).toSeconds(),
          },
          compressionFormat: 'UNCOMPRESSED',
          encryptionConfiguration: {
            noEncryptionConfig: 'NoEncryption',
          },
          prefix: 'event-logs',
          errorOutputPrefix: 'event-logs-logs',
          roleArn: firehoseRole.roleArn,
        },
      }
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

The `CallAwsService` is direct related to [AWS SDK service integrations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/supported-services-awssdk.html) documentation.

We can see the pattern is:

```bash
arn:aws:states:::aws-sdk:[serviceName]:[apiAction].[serviceIntegrationPattern]
```

You can check the Kinesis Firehose SDK operations list in the AWS SDK documentation:

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-firehose/#client-commands-operations-list

With that in mind, we can create a service integration with Firehose using:

```js
new tasks.CallAwsService(this, "FirehoseTask", {
  service: "firehose",
  action: "putRecord",
  parameters: {
    DeliveryStreamName: firehoseDeliveryStream.ref,
    Record: {
      Data: stepfunctions.JsonPath.stringAt("$.Payload"),
    },
  },
  iamResources: [firehoseDeliveryStream.attrArn],
})
```

Make sure your Step Function IAM Role can put records into the kinesis stream:

```js
stateMachine.addToRolePolicy(
  new iam.PolicyStatement({
    effect: iam.Effect.ALLOW,
    actions: ["firehose:PutRecord"],
    resources: [firehoseDeliveryStream.attrArn],
  })
);
```

A complete pseudo-code:

```js
const definition = stepfunctions.Chain.start(
  new tasks.LambdaInvoke(this, "LambdaTask", {
    lambdaFunction: functionProcessor,
  })
).next(
new tasks.CallAwsService(this, "FirehoseTask", {
  service: "firehose",
  action: "putRecord",
  parameters: {
    DeliveryStreamName: firehoseDeliveryStream.ref,
    Record: {
      Data: stepfunctions.JsonPath.stringAt("$.Payload"),
    },
  },
  iamResources: [firehoseDeliveryStream.attrArn],
})
);
const stateMachine = new stepfunctions.StateMachine(this, "StateMachine", {
  definition,
});
stateMachine.addToRolePolicy(
  new iam.PolicyStatement({
    effect: iam.Effect.ALLOW,
    actions: ["firehose:PutRecord"],
    resources: [firehoseDeliveryStream.attrArn],
  })
);
```